# Using .htaccess to get content from directory for sub-domain

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, url-rewriting, masking

I've read a tonne of questions on this and tried a few solutions, but I'm just not getting the results I want.

I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cp\.example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/gamepanel/public/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Which doesn't quite work as intended. When I navigate to cp.example.net I am redirected to `http://example.net/gamepanel/public/`

What I want to have happen is for `cp.example.net` to show the content at `http://example.net/gamepanel/public`, whilst showing the subdomain in the URL.

Also `cp.example.net/user` should show content from `example.net/gamepanel/public/user`

Some help on achieving this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can't simply do cross-domain (internal) rewrites like this. You'll need to set up your server as a proxy and use mod_proxy (which itself comes with security issues). Is this your own server?

Comment: It is my own domain. After continuing to research I found that associating the sub domain was the better way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging, associating the sub domain with my directory was the better way to do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName cp.example.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/gamepanel/public
        <Directory /var/www/gamepanel/public>
            Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested... but should work

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cp.example.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/gamepanel/public/ [R=301,L]
```